# Read from hdfs using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

At work we are using [Scalding](https://github.com/twitter/scalding) and I was required to read out some stuff saved in HDFS for further processing.

Being a Scala noob I'm having a hard time getting it all to work and just finding out documentation on the topic.

My question is twofold:

What is the most straight forward way to read from HDFS?

Where is a good resource on the topic, with examples or tutorials?

Comment: 1) Take a java example (I believe there are tons of them) 2) scalify it (val's instead of full declarations and so on)

Comment: Care to point me to a good one?

Comment: I'm not a hadoop guy (so don't think it is good enough), but why not [this one](http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/12/28/Reading-data-from-HDFS-even-if-it-is-compressed.html)?

Comment: Mmmm... seems like I miss some dependency, I can't resolve the required classes (Configuration, Filesystem... etc)

Comment: Actually. I'm doing it wrong. Scalding already abstracts me away all the pieces of Hadoop that I need and just using [TextLine](http://twitter.github.io/scalding/#com.twitter.scalding.TextLine) should be enough...